# Trouble applying CSS to a li - ultimate specificity fails

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble applying a CSS style to a li. Surely the problem cannot be specificity but I don't know how to select the li's - I just want to be able to style these li's white and apply hover effects that are the same as the brand title.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

```css
/* MAKES HEADER NAVBAR NO WIDER THAN 960PX */
.width-960px { max-width: 960px; }

.no-padding-unless-mobile {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: #3C7AAD;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #D5D5D5;
}

/* I can't be any more specific than this... */
.navbar .navbar-default .navbar-static-top .container .width-960px .no-padding-unless-mobile .collapse .navbar-collapse .navHeaderCollapse .nav .navbar-nav .navbar-right ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container width-960px no-padding-unless-mobile">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>

                <!-- MOBILE BUTTON - VIEWABLE ON MOBILE SIZED BROWSERS ONLY -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="matches.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="products.html">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.navbar-right is already the ul ... only use like below
you could also use ul.navbar-right to select it. But i think you got the problem.

```css
/* MAKES HEADER NAVBAR NO WIDER THAN 960PX */
.width-960px { max-width: 960px; }

.no-padding-unless-mobile {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: #3C7AAD;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #D5D5D5;
}

/* I can't be any more specific than this... */
.navbar-right li a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container width-960px no-padding-unless-mobile">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>

                <!-- MOBILE BUTTON - VIEWABLE ON MOBILE SIZED BROWSERS ONLY -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="matches.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="products.html">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
.navbar .navbar-default .navbar-static-top .container .width-960px .no-padding-unless-mobile .collapse .navbar-collapse .navHeaderCollapse .nav .navbar-nav .navbar-right ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

With this:

```
.nav li a {
    color: #fff;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    color: #D5D5D5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{ color:#fff !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover { background:#fff  !important; color:#333  !important;}`

```css
.width-960px { max-width: 960px; }

.no-padding-unless-mobile {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: #3C7AAD;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #D5D5D5;
}

/* I can't be any more specific than this... */
.navbar .navbar-default .navbar-static-top .container .width-960px .no-padding-unless-mobile .collapse .navbar-collapse .navHeaderCollapse .nav .navbar-nav .navbar-right ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{ color:#fff !important;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover { background:#fff  !important; color:#333  !important;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container width-960px no-padding-unless-mobile">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>

                <!-- MOBILE BUTTON - VIEWABLE ON MOBILE SIZED BROWSERS ONLY -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <!-- HAMBURGER MENU -->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="matches.html">Link 1</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="products.html">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
```